# MySQL autoincrement index reuse

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models as follow

```
class Product > ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_to_image_items, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :product_images, through: :product_to_image_items
end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and the join model

```
class ProductToImageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :product_image
end
```

In the web interface, the user can select a batch of images to associate with a product. However, to keep the math simple, everytime the user edits the product-image association, all previous associations are destroyed and new associations are created. What I am worried about is that eventually the index of each association will be very large, and close to the limit of the maximum number of records in a table, even though there are only a few records in the table.
For instance, I have a product Doll. Doll is associated with images doll1.jpg, doll2.jpg. Now suppose that I want to use doll3.jpg, but no longer want to use doll2.jpg, the post request will tell the server that we are now using doll1.jpg and doll3.jpg. The server will just remove all previous associations, and create 2 new associations.

What I can do is to inspect each association and only create new if not exist, and also have to detect which associations are to be destroyed from the web interface.

I am looking for both an improvement and a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Could you also add your attempt so that there is a base to start with?

Comment: Hi Vee, I have already mentioned my attempt above. I'll add an example to the description.